# No coincide mi clave ssh pública con la de github

Tags: github

Me cree la clave, uso Ubuntu 22.04 la añadi a ssh-agent pero al momento de hacer
`ssh -T git@github.com`
me aparece un fingerprinter key diferente al que me genero github en settings con diferente tipo de codificación. La que uso es RSA y la que me aparece en la terminal ED25519. Otra cosa rara que tengo es que no tengo el archivo known_hosts generado. no esta en la carpeta .ssh como deberia aparecer. No se que hacer

Comment: Usa ssh-add -l para listar las claves que tienes generadas, es posible que hayas generado una ED25519 en vez de la RSA. Y el archivo known_hosts se generará al realizar la conexión con github, cosa que no ha sucedido aún.

Comment: Es que es la primera clave que genero. Anteriormente genere una GPG para docker pero no se como se genero esa clave ED o si viene generada por defecto en la instalación de Ubuntu